# Problems with ts header

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I write this question to see if anyone might know what happens to this piece of code. Wrote the following lines with the intention of removing the header bits of a TS packet, but I have several problems with the code.

This is the code:

```
static GstPadProbeReturn TS_Packet (GstPad *padd, GstPadProbeInfo *info, gpointer user_data)
{
       guint8 *byte;
       gchar *paquete;
       gsize   count_print=0;

       GstBitReader *bytes_cabecera;

       GstMapInfo map;
       GstBuffer *buffer;

       if (GST_EVENT_TYPE (GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_DATA (info)) != GST_EVENT_EOS){

          buffer = GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_BUFFER (info);            
          buffer = gst_buffer_make_writable (buffer);   

          gst_buffer_map (buffer, &map, GST_MAP_WRITE);
          byte=(guint8 *)map.data;

          while(count_print<map.size){

              g_print("\n");
              g_print("-Paquete numero del paquete: %d-\n",i);
              i=i+1;

              for(n=0; n<8 ;n++){
                  paquete[n]=byte[n+count_print];
                  g_print(" %02x ",byte[count_print+n]);
              }/*for*/
              g_print("\n");

              bytes_cabecera=gst_bit_reader_new(paquete, map.size);
              g_print("       ->stream header (32bits)-\n");
              guint8 sync = gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,8);

              if(sync==71){
                  g_print("         Sync_byte: %02x (available) \n",sync);
              }else{
                  g_print("         Sync_byte: %02x (no available) \n",sync);
              }/*else*/

              guint8 transport_error_indicator = gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,1);
              if(transport_error_indicator==0){
                  g_print("         Transport_error_indicator: %d (No_error)\n", transport_error_indicator);
              }else if (transport_error_indicator==1){
                  g_print("         Transport_error_indicator: %d (Error)\n", transport_error_indicator);
              }/*cierro casos de error*/

              guint8 Payload_start_indicator = gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,1);

              if(Payload_start_indicator==0){
                  g_print("         Payload_start_indicator: %d (No_Star_indicator_avalible)\n", Payload_start_indicator);
              }else if (Payload_start_indicator==1){
                  g_print("         Payload_start_indicator: %d (Start_indicator_avalible)\n", Payload_start_indicator);
              }/*cierro casos de payload start indicator*/

              guint8 transport_priority = gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,1);

              if(transport_priority==0){
                  g_print("         Transport_priority: %d (No_Priority_avalibe)\n", transport_priority);
              }else if (transport_priority==1){
                  g_print("         Transport_priority: %d (Priority_avalible)\n", transport_priority);
              }/*cierro casos de Priority*/

              guint16 pid_ts= gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint16_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,13);
              g_print("         PID: %02d \n",pid_ts);

              guint8 scramblin_control= gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,2);

              if(scramblin_control==0){
                g_print("         Scrambling control: %d (Not scrambled)\n", scramblin_control);
              }else if (scramblin_control==1){
                g_print("         Scrambling control: %d ( Reserved for future use)\n", scramblin_control);
              }else if (scramblin_control==2){
                g_print("         Scrambling control: %d (Scrambled with even key)\n", scramblin_control);
              }else if (scramblin_control==3){
                g_print("         Scrambling control: %d (Scrambled with odd key)\n", scramblin_control);
              }/*cierro el if del scramblin*/

               guint8 Adaptation_field_exist= gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,1);

               if(Adaptation_field_exist==0){
                 g_print("         Adaptation field_exist: %d (No exist)\n", Adaptation_field_exist);
               }else if (Adaptation_field_exist==1){
                 g_print("         Adaptation field_exist: %d (Exist)\n", Adaptation_field_exist);
               }/*cAdaptation field*/

               guint8 Contains_payload= gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,1);

               if(Contains_payload==0){
                 g_print("         Contains payload: %d (No exist)\n", Contains_payload);
               }else if (Contains_payload==1){
                 g_print("         Contains payload: %d (Exist)\n", Contains_payload);
               }/*cAdaptation field*/

              guint8 Continuity_counter= gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,4);
              g_print("         Continuity counter: %d \n",Continuity_counter);



              if(Adaptation_field_exist==1){
                  g_print("          ->Adaptation Field-\n");

                  guint8 Adaptation_field_lenght= gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,8);
                  g_print("            Adaptation field lenght: %d \n",Adaptation_field_lenght);

                  guint8 Discontinuity_indicator= gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,1);
                  g_print("            Discontinuity indicator: %d \n",Discontinuity_indicator);

                  guint8 Random_acces= gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,1);
                  g_print("            Random Access indicator: %d \n",Random_acces);

                  guint8 Stream_priority= gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,1);
                  g_print("            ES_priority indicator: %d \n",Stream_priority);

                  guint8 PCR_Flag= gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,1);
                  g_print("            Flag PCR: %d \n",PCR_Flag);

                  guint8 OPCR_Flag= gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,1);
                  g_print("            Flag OPCR: %d \n",OPCR_Flag);

                  //guint8 Splicing_point_flag= gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,1);
                  //g_print("          Flag Splicing point: %d \n",Splicing_point_flag);

                  //guint8 Transport_private_data_flag= gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,1);
                  //g_print("          Flag Transport private data point: %d \n",Transport_private_data_flag);

                  //guint8 Adaptation_field_extension_flag= gst_bit_reader_get_bits_uint8_unchecked(bytes_cabecera,1);
                  //g_print("          Adaptation field extension flag: %d \n",Adaptation_field_extension_flag);

              }/*cierro el caso para mi adaptation field*/

              g_print("\n");

              count_print=count_print+188;

          }/*cierro el while*/

          gst_buffer_unmap (buffer, &map);

       }/*general*/

       return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;

 }/*pad probe*/
```

problems and doubts:

1) when I add in more element of analysis "Splicing Point Flag" eclipse does not execute the code, somo shows the line g: print, and complete.

2) whether the conditional if (n, n <8; n ++) give it a value greater than 8 only shows a limited number of packages of a ts file, not all.
Does anyone know why these problems, or another way to do the same thing differently?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I feel very foolish. I found the problem. The problem is to define the variable as a package the definitive gchar when having to work should be defined as guint8 and with a certain size. If we create a pipeline with ts demux, we can put this line of code to visualize and study the bits that make up the TS header.

with this modification, I can now resize one of 8 188 and see all items.